# How do you undo a Windows XP "Remove from this list"?

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu, undo

How do you undo a Windows XP "Remove from this list"?

Comment: 1. Find the shortcut you removed.
2. Right-click it and choose "Pin to start menu."

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I don't want it to stick - I only want it to revert to "frequency use" rules

Comment: @cyberkiwi: There's nothing to "revert"; the same rules are being used. The only thing you did is reset the usage counters to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only want it to revert to "frequency use" rules

Using the "Remove from this list" menu item *does not* change the rules used. All you did is zero the usage counters of your application; it should re-appear in a couple of launches.

- If it doesn't, try:

  ```
  reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\Applications\cmd.exe /f
  reg delete HKLM\Software\Classes\Applications\cmd.exe /f
  reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\{75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}\Count /f /v "HRZR_EHACVQY:%pfvqy2%\Npprffbevrf\Pbzznaq Cebzcg.yax"
  reg delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\{75048700-EF1F-11D0-9888-006097DEACF9}\Count /f /v "HRZR_EHACNGU:P:\JVAQBJF\flfgrz32\pzq.rkr"
  taskkill /im explorer.exe /f && explorer.exe
  ```
- ...or clear the program list and re-fill it with the most used programs.
- ...or simply *pin it there*.

---

If you do want to forbid a Start Menu item from appearing on the Frequently Used Programs list, use [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) → *Taskbar and Start Menu → Start Menu* and (un)mark the program.

Comment: I don't but that. I removed the command prompt N-years ago, and it is one my most used programs. It has not come back.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: See edit. (Also, it's "grawity", not "gra".)

Comment: replies only require 3 characters. sorry to mangle your name but it's actually an SE feature. Anyway, that wasn't my problem, it was a VS2008 batch file that has somehow usurped cmd.exe's counts

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Feature, but not a requirement.